# Need SpriteKit collision to occur only on first contact

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I currently have two nodes in use, one of which is a boat (polygon) and the other a straight vertical rectangle. The boat needs to be a polygon so that it can be hit via projectiles, however this causes me problems when it collides with the vertical rectangle due to the many sides it's coming into contact with. Hence a piece of code I want ran only once is instead ran multiple times.

Is there anyway to make the collision detection only function for the first contact so that it doesn't repeatedly call?

I'm aware of setting the categoryBitMask to 0 however doing so renders the boat unable to be hit by anything else- something I don't want. Additionally I considered using a boolean variable to only run the code once whilst the boat is passing through, however as previously mentioned, due to the different sides, the code think it's passed through when in fact it's just hitting another side of the boat.

I don't have much code to show here other than setting physics bodies so I don't think it's necessary, but inside didBeginContact() I'm using a categoryBitMask comparison to check for collisions.

I may have not explained this very well, in which case I apologize, my English is not the best!

If anyone can help, it'd be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?  I'm having similar issues with it detecting multiple collisions when just hitting the ground.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the individual physics bodies of your ship into a single body with

```
+ (SKPhysicsBody *)bodyWithBodies:(NSArray *)bodies
```

and then test for contacts with the composite body instead of the individual components.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot first thing tomorrow, I'm getting too tired to code!

Answer (score 0):

If you are subclassing your node then simply create a BOOL property for it.

```
BOOL alreadyHit;
```

If you are not subclassing, use the SKNode's `userData` dictionary and create an entry for the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't think a BOOL would work as the shape's collision is not one continuous flow. For example if a rectangle is caught in a collision, it's shape is consistent. A polygon (mine at least) would have gaps between collision detection as it's moving, hence if I toggled the BOOL at the first contact, I'd then need to untoggle it as it ends the final contact which I can't think of a way to do. Ideally I need, if contact, bool on, node has fully passed through, bool off.

Comment: @Chris - That's different from what you initially asked. Your problem is not a programming one but a logical one.